# How to extract mutually disjoint elements(lists) of a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have a list of lists, for example:

```
my_list = {{1,2,9},{2,3,7},{5,6,9},{8,10,11}}
```

I want to manipulate the list such that it contains only all the mutually disjoint elements of the list, as follows:

```
my_list = {{1,2,9},{8,10,11}}
```

or

```
my_list = {{2,3,7},{5,6,9},{8,10,11}}
```

Preferably, the instances with more elements, like the second one.

Thanks in advance for any help and guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would turn your question into a graph problem. Consider your lists as vertices, and an edge between two vertices exists if there is a common element. Then, [`FindIndependentVertexSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentVertexSet.html) should find the set with the maximal number of vertices with no common edge, i.e., what you're interested in. Here is the code:

```
maximalDisjointSubset[list_]:=Module[{vertices = Range@Length@list,edges},
    edges=Cases[
        Subsets[vertices,2],
        {i_,j_} /; Intersection @@ list[[{i,j}]] != {} :> i<->j
    ];
    list[[First @ FindIndependentVertexSet @ Graph[vertices,edges]]]
]
```

For your example:

```
maximalDisjointSubset[{{1,2,9},{2,3,7},{5,6,9},{8,10,11}}]
```

{{2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}

Note that finding a maximal independent vertex set is an NP-hard optimization problem.

Comment: Many thanks Carl for your answer; yes, that's exactly what I want as well. Actually, I was thinking to use the "FindIndependentVertexSet", but by considering every individual number as a vertex and not every list. Considering the lists solves the problem. That's great.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
fn=Module[{ms = Subsets[#, {2, Length@#}]}, 
  Take[Reverse[Pick[ms, And @@ DisjointQ @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ ms]],UpTo[1]]] &;

mylist = {{1, 2, 9}, {2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}
fn@mylist
```

> {{{2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}}

BTW, don't use underscores willy-nilly (note I used *mylist* vs *my_list*), or you'll be in for some nasty surprises.

If you want all the instances, in order of length (as opposed to one of the longest cases as in OP), use:

```
fn2 = Module[{ms = Subsets[#, {2, Length@#}]}, 
             Pick[ms, And @@ DisjointQ @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ ms]] &;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer; It's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for small lists:

```
my = {{1, 2, 9}, {2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}};
g = RelationGraph[Intersection[#1, #2] == {} &, my];
FindClique[g, Infinity, All]
```

yields:

```
{{{2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}, {{1, 2, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}}
```

Comment: slightly simpler `RelationGraph[DisjointQ, my]`? (+1)

Comment: @kglr thank you for the refinement and the vote

Comment: Many thanks for your answers and guide. Actually, Clique is not what I need, but I'll test RelationGraph as well.

Comment: @Marilla sorry for the misunderstanding. Good luck

Comment: no problem at all; I appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're asking, but perhaps this is your solution:

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 9}, {2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}};
list2 = {{1, 2, 9}, {8, 10, 11}};
Complement[list1, list2]
```

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. Actually, the list2 would be the list to find; So, I don't have it from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{1, 2, 9}, {2, 3, 7}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 11}};

DeleteDuplicates[list, IntersectingQ]
```

> {{1, 2, 9}, {8, 10, 11}}

---

As your *Preferably*

```
First[FindIndependentVertexSet[RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, list]]]
```

> {{2,3,7},{5,6,9},{8,10,11}}